# Seams showing in older home drywall

Tags: drywall

I live in a house built in 1948 in the upper midwest. How can I repair the horizontal seams on the walls and most of the ceilings.  I'm wondering if they didn't use tape or didn't mud over the tape when built.  I'm guessing the walls were finished with wallpaper back then.   I put wallpaper in a bedroom and don't notice it.  I really don't want to put wallpaper everywhere. There are no cracks. Just a slight indent at each seam.

Comment: A picture of the area would help us know the extent of your issue.  Normally lines or small trenches are filled with spackle or compound and feathered to blend with the surrounding surface, then painted.

Comment: Tape and mud might have been used, but not done well.

Comment: Unless the house has previously been rehabbed, I'd be surprised if you had *drywall.*

Comment: I have done some home improvement but not with my wall so didn't know if spackly or compound would be enough.   That's something I cam do.  And yes I understand the feathering..  I really appreciate everyone's input.  Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can mud the joints (probably want to clean well first for good adhesion) before repainting. I've "corrected" some sloppy 1970's drywall finishing work 30+ years after the fact. Nothing all that special about it, just bothering to do enough coats and wait for them to properly dry before the next one, until shrinkage stops being an issue.

Comment: I was hoping that something that easy was all I needed to do.  Thank you.